# .net Maui Android App loses internet connection when disconnecting from IOT device

Tags: android, .net, mobile, maui, cellular-network

I have an issue in my .net Maui Android application where the app seems to lose internet connection after I disconnect from an IOT device when using mobile data (I do not have this issue when the user is on WIFI).

I say the app loses connection because if I switch to the web browser on the phone then I can still access websites so the phone does have an active network connection.

This is the process at the moment.
The Phone connects to the access point (IOT device)
The users network credential are posted to the IOT device so that it can connect to the internet
The phone is then disconnected from the interface and still has mobile data signal

Expected
The subsequent call to our services completes successfully

Actual
The subsequent call fails as unable to Unable to resolve host "": No address associated with hostname

Here is the code I am using to connect to the IOT device

```
                    WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
                    WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder
                        .SetSsid(ssid)
                        .SetWpa2Passphrase(password)
                        .Build();

                    var networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                        .AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi)!
                        .RemoveCapability(NetCapability.Internet)!
                        .SetNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)!
                        .Build();
                    
                    var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService)!;
                    _customNetworkCallback = new CustomNetworkCallback(connectivityManager);
                    connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(networkRequest!, _customNetworkCallback);

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
```

and here is the code I am using to disconnect from the iot device

```
var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService)!;
                try
                {
                    //Just try to do this, might not need to
                    if(_customNetworkCallback != null)
                        connectivityManager.UnregisterNetworkCallback(_customNetworkCallback);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
```

Here is the custom netowrk callback

```
sealed class CustomNetworkCallback : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
{
    private readonly ConnectivityManager _connectivityManager = null!;
    public CustomNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager)
    {
        _connectivityManager = connectivityManager;
    }
    public override void OnLosing(Network network, int maxMsToLive) => base.OnLosing(network, maxMsToLive);

    public override void OnAvailable(Network network)
    {
        base.OnAvailable(network);
        _connectivityManager.BindProcessToNetwork(network);
    }
    public override void OnLost(Network network) => base.OnLost(network);
}
```

The Android phone I am using is Android 13.0 API version 33

I have tried not calling the UnregisterNetworkCallback and letting the phone figure out that the IOT device is no longer connected (The iot device reboots after you send it network credential so the connection is lost at this point). The strange thing is that it works fine when the user is on WIFI, the phone just reverts back to the wifi connection they had prior to connecting to the IOT device.